# Error on using Fody [ImplementPropertyChanged]

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, fody

I am Using VS 2017 Community Edition
I am creating MVVM pattern. After i installed fody i got error on my code while the instructor of the tutorial implemented it on vs 2015
here is the code:

```
using PropertyChanged;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace GProject_MVVM.ViewModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A base view model that fires Property Changed events as needed
    /// </summary>
    [ImplementPropertyChanged] // **I got error here**
    public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The event that is fired when any child property changes its value
        /// </summary>
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = (sender, e) => { };
        /// <summary>
        /// Call this to fire <see cref="PropertyChanged"/> event
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="name"></param>
        public void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));

        }
    }
}
```

[ImplementPropertyChanged] should not make error on this point the instructor implemented it successfully so is thier anything missing on my code ? 
The error says:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS0619  'ImplementPropertyChangedAttribute' is obsolete: 'This
>   configuration option has been deprecated. The use of this attribute
>   was to add INotifyPropertyChanged to a class with its associated event
>   definition. After that all classes that implement
>   INotifyPropertyChanged have their properties weaved, weather they have
>   the ImplementPropertyChangedAttribute or not. This attribute was often
>   incorrectly interpreted as an opt in approach to having properties
>   weaved, which was never the intent nor how it ever operated. This
>   attribute has been replaced by
>   AddINotifyPropertyChangedInterfaceAttribute.' GProject_MVVM   c:\users\ahmed
>   hussainy\documents\visual studio
>   2017\Projects\GProject_MVVM\GProject_MVVM\ViewModel\BaseViewModel.cs  9   Active

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The exception already states the answer.

> ImplementPropertyChangedAttribute' is obsolete: 'This configuration
>   option has been deprecated. The use of this attribute was to add
>   INotifyPropertyChanged to a class with its associated event
>   definition. After that all classes that implement
>   INotifyPropertyChanged have their properties weaved, weather they have
>   the ImplementPropertyChangedAttribute or not.

With the new version of Fody.PropertyChanged you don't need to add the attribute any longer. Just make that class you want to be weaved implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and it will work.

So basically just **remove / delete `[ImplementPropertyChanged]`** and it will compile and weave (if the weaver is present in `FodyWeavers.xml`)

Answer (score 1):

If you originally used this attribute exactly the way it was meant to be used, you should replace it with `[AddINotifyPropertyChangedInterface]`.

This way Fody will add the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface to your class, and then the weaver will implement it properly.